# jQuery won't update textarea after manipulated

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Hey so I have a text area in my HTML and whenever I you click on a file name in the list it puts the contents of the file in that text area, it works great clicking back and forth between files. As soon as i edit something within the textarea then go try to click the file names again it just doesn't do anything or update that text area anymore.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var currentFile;



$(document).ready(function()
{
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "getFiles.php", false);
request.send();
var result = request.responseText;
$("#fileNames").html(request.responseText);
});



$(document).ready(function()
{
$("li").click(function()
{
    currentFile = $(this).text();
    $("#currentFile").text(currentFile);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "getFileContents.php?fileName="+currentFile, false);
    request.send();
    var result = request.responseText;
    $("#fileContents").text(result);
});
 });



function saveFile()
{
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var contents = $("#fileContents").text();
request.open("GET", "saveFile.php?fileName="+currentFile+"&fileContents="+contents, false);
request.send();
}


</script>


<style type="text/css">

ul.fileList li
{
    background-color:blue;
}


#fileContents
{
    resize: none;
}

 </style>


</head>
<body>
<div id="currentFile">No File Selected</div

<br />

<ul id="fileNames" class="fileList">

</ul>

<br />

<textarea id="fileContents" cols="25" rows="5">No Contents</textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="saveFile();" value="Save" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Syntax error here
`<div id="currentFile">No File Selected</div`
NO closing tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `.val()` to get and set the text in a textarea

```
$("#fileContents").val(result);

var contents = $("#fileContents").val();
```